# Make a code loop 100 times with a text on Serial Monitor

Tags: led, loop

Ok, this is my code:

```
int rosso = 13;
int verde = 12;
int blu = 11;
int count = 0;
String command_on, command_off;
String s;
String enough = "stop";

void setup(){
  pinMode(rosso, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(verde, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(blu, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  command_on = String("on");
  command_off = String("off");
}

void redToBlue(){
  if(count < 100) {   
  rgb(0,255,0);
  delay(100);
  rgb(0,0,0);
  delay(100);
  rgb(255,0,0);
  delay(100);
  rgb(0,0,0);
  count = count+1;  
  }
}

void switchOff(){
  rgb(0,0,0);
  delay(100);
}

boolean wait_command(){
  if(s == command_on){
    redToBlue();
  }
  if(s == command_off){
  switchOff();
  }
}
    
void accendi(){
  if(s == command_on){
  redToBlue();
  }
  
  if(s == command_off){
  switchOff();
  }
}

void rgb(int r, int g, int b){
  analogWrite(rosso, r);
  analogWrite(blu, b);
  analogWrite(verde, g);
}
  
void loop(){
 s = Serial.readString();
 Serial.println("What I have to do? ");
 wait_command();
}
```

When I open the Serial Monitor and type "on" there, the redToblue() function must loop 100 times. But in my case loops only one time then it stops. I think I have to change something inside loop() function and on redToBlue()...

Answer (score 1):

You `loop()` function is the one that will be called when the program runs and it will keep looping around until you stop it.  So at the moment you have `loop()` doing the following:

1. Reading a string from the serial connection
2. Displaying a message to the serial connection
3. Parsing the string that was read and acting upon it.

So when your code runs you see it print the message and maybe do something with the light and then it stops/freezes.  Its not really frozen, its waiting for you to enter an answer.

So if you really want it to ask what to do and then then loop 100 times you need to do this:

1. Display the message.
2. Read the data.
3. Call `wait_command()` (after you have modified it)

void redToBlue(){
for (int count = 0; count < 100; ++count) {
rgb(0,255,0);
delay(100);
rgb(0,0,0);
delay(100);
rgb(255,0,0);
delay(100);
rgb(0,0,0);
}
} ***// Sorry I can't get the code to format.***

I think you could also refactor the function to loop over an array of 4 rgb values.  I don't now if that would be better for the processor, it would look nicer :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you want, but if you expect after a single command `on` to have it looped 100 times, you need to call the `redToBlue` function in every loop (within `wait_command`, that checks for a boolean if the `on` command has been requested, and when so, call the `redToBlue` function. When the `off` command is set, you reset the boolean.

Also `wait_command` is not a good name, as it does not wait for a command, but processes it.

Comment: yes I would like that If I type "on" loop 100 times, and if I type "off" doesn't do nothing, and rgb led is off.

Comment: It will also stop before 100 if you type "off" when 100 loops are not reached yet.